# How to import a module into another module

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-import

This is the structure of my project:

```
project (folder)
   main.py
   assets (folder)
      a.py
      b.py
```

When I import module a into module b and run main.py, I get `No module named 'a'`.

Yet if I run b.py directly, it imports a.py just fine.

a and b are in the same directory, so what am I missing? FWIW, I am using Python 3.10.

main.py:

```
import assets.b as bb
```

a.py:

```
def func(x):
    print(x)
```

b.py:

```
import a
a.func('hello')
```

Comment: try `from .a import func`, what does `does not work` mean? what error are you getting?

Comment: the error I get is in the post. I just tried what you suggested, and running b.py still works fine, but running main.py still gives the same error

Comment: Replace `import a` with `from . import a` (`from .a import func; func('hello')` also works fine)

Comment: Using from . import a allows main.py to run correctly, but if I try to run b.py directly with this it gives: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: *if I run b.py directly*.  Are you cd-ing into the *assets* directory to do that?  If so, keep in mind `sys.path` always includes the current directory. Which makes `a` importable.

Comment: what I meant here was if I have the module open in vs code and hit play with b.py. Doing this causes the error still using . import, but does not cause the error when running the main.py file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `b.py` as follows

```
from . import a 
a.func('hello')
```

or

```
from assets import a
a.func('hello')
```

In first case, we are telling interpreter to check in the same location as file. In second case, we are just using a fullpath. Tested with python 3.10.1 and 3.6

If you are using a folder structure, it is always best to fix you execution path and relative path according to your `main.py`. Implies running `python3.10 b.py` from `assets` is not acceptable.

---

In case, you want the functionality to do `python3.10 b.py` from `assets` folder and also `python3.10 main.py` then update the code as follows.

```
try:
  from . import a
except:
  import a

a.func('hello')
```

If you are sticking to a IDE like PyCharm then such errors are easy to spot and fix.

Comment: Just tried this and when I run main.py I still get 'No module named 'a''.      Do I have to reference the __init__.py file in main.py?

Comment: @ah2Bwise Please check the updated answer now!

Comment: @ah2Bwise - sorry for confusion! Can you try updated answer now?

Comment: NP, Appreciate the help. Running this allows main.py to work fine, but now running b.py gives "attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Comment: So, both the methods mentioned in the answer worked for me. I used Python 3.8.9

Comment: @sam It only works if you don’t treat `b.py` as an entry point (i.e. by running `python b.py` or `python -m b`). A rather annoying (and unnecessary) limitation of Python’s module system.

Comment: I agree. If you got a working answer. Kindly update it as answer.